# Open Visual Studio with solution and specific file and line

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmd

I have to open VS via command line. It has to open a file in a solution and set the cursor in a specific line. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: the list of commands is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/devenv-command-line-switches?view=vs-2019 I don't think its possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of works for me:

```
devenv "Path\To\Your\Solution" /edit "Path\To\Your\File" /command "Edit.GoTo 123"
```

Based on these resources:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/devenv-command-line-switches?view=vs-2019
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/edit-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/command-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/go-to-command?view=vs-2019

Comment: how does it work for you? for me it opens both the sln file and the specified file with a simple window layout, but it did not open the sln.

Comment: Same here @LimTaSheng

Comment: Same here, does not work